# How to inject two form answers from inline command execution (shell)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a shell script that packages an application. This script, once executed, asks for SVN_USER & SVN_PASSWORD. Then exports them to the system, then runs packaging commands.

The thing is, i want to execute that script from Jenkins over ssh.

In other words, i need a way to inject my username & password in an inline command.

( i don't have the right to edit the script so i can not use $1 $2 and pass them as parameters, the script only accepts those two variables as a form input ).

i tried :

- export SVN_USER=foo
- export SVN_PASSWORD=bar
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@10.12.50.254 'sh /base/myscript.sh appname'

--> The connectivity is fine, the script starts, asks for username and password, and fails execution since it didnt receive the information required.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only way you will be able to do this is by setting the environment inside the remote command string ex.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@10.12.50.254 'SVN_USER=foo SVN_PASSWORD=bar sh /base/myscript.sh appname'
```

Although SSH provides a `SendEnv` option that in principle allows you to pass environment settings from local to remote, that relies on a corresponding `AllowEnv` setting in the remote `sshd_config` file: at least in the Ubuntu, the defaults only permit locale-related environment settings i.e.

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

and

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: Thanks much, it works, but it displays the user/password, any way to hide them ? thanks again !

Comment: @YassineBOUMAJANE the command itself shouldn't display anything - maybe they are being output by the script? if so, you could redirect the script's output to `/dev/null`

Comment: Jenkins shows the whole command at the time of execution, still, i consider this thread resolved because the solution you provided answers very well the question in the topic. I will open another topic concerning how to transfer secrets from jenkins inside an ssh shell script. Thanks a lot again Steeldriver !!